# Bamboo nunit runner not finding tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, bamboo

I'm developing testing framework using .net + selenium with Nunit 2.6.4 runner.

I configured bamboo to run test in that way:

1. Checkout from repository
2. Parametrize tests
3. Nuget restore
4. MsBuild with option /p:Configuration=Debug
5. Nunit runner

In nunit test runner task im using Nunit 2.6.4 version.

For the "NUnit Test Files" im passing the path to : .\SeleniumProject.Shop\SeleniumProject.Shop\bin\debug\SeleniumProject.Shop.dll

I'm sure that this file exist in this path, becouse I checked that using script task that prints list of files in .\SeleniumProject.Shop\SeleniumProject.Shop\bin\debug\ to make sure that I have SeleniumProject.Shop.dl there.

But on 5th task Im getting an error:

> Parsing test results under C:\buildAgent\xml-data\build-dir\SHOP-WEB-JOB1...
>
> Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found. Finished task
>
> 'FronPageLinks' with result: Failed

I'm sure that tests can be found in SeleniumProject.Shop.dll, becouse I checked that manually on local mashine using the nunit.exe

Does anyone have some ideas why is that happened?
Another funny think is that bamboo find the test two times (in like 30 attempt) and the test were executed

Answer (score 0):

You must set the 'Result Filename' property with the path of the xml ([link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/nunit-runner-289277059.html))

**EDIT**

You also have to add a NUnit Parser task and then set the path of the generated xml ([link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/nunit-parser-289277054.html)).